# References/pointers and methods... trying to learn good c++ practice

Tags: c++, methods

I am coming from 15 years of MATLAB and trying to teach myself C++. I do a lot of work with modeling/simulation for orbits, and I am trying to make some very specifically tuned tools for specific analysis.

I have been reading about the right times to use variables, references, or pointers, but does this matter when using a method? Does using a method on an object create a copy?

I have a basic for loop iterating over an "Orbit" object which essentially has all of the epoch orbital elements, then pass it a time in seconds, and the method returns the eci position vector. Eventually I want to switch to passing a LAT/LON coordinate and calculating line of sight.

But for now my main question is do "methods" on a custom class create copies or is there a better way for me to code this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Orbit.h"
#include <ppl.h>
#include <vector>

int main()
{

    Orbit myOrbit2(1000, 89, 130, 100);

        // Basic for loop
    for (int i = 1; i < 86400 * 365; ++i)
    {
    myOrbit2.get_eci(i);
    }

        // me trying to mess with parallel loops
    //Concurrency::parallel_for(1, 86400 * 365,
    //  [&](int i)
    //  {
    //      myOrbit2.get_eci(i);
    //  });
}
```

Comment: _"... do methods" on a custom class create copies..."_ not usually; but they can if the implementer wishes them to.  Without seeing the implementation of `Orbit ::get_eci` we can't be sure.

Comment: I worry that "Does using a method on an object create a copy?" is read and understood differently by users here than you mean it. I recommend to elaborate. Describe what that means to you. Give examples of "making a copy" and "not making a copy". Maybe in prose, maybe in terms of programming languages you are familiar with (in that case consider also tagging them).

Comment: Please excuse the negativeness of the following comment, it is meant to save you some frustration, not to hurt you or make fun of you. If you have been using matlab for a long time on topics like orbital simulation (including terms I have never heard before - though that might only be my lack of knowledge) and now find matlab to be too slow, then it will probably not be you who is the right programmer to solve any related topic in a newly learned programming language. Not to speak of getting them solved more efficiently. I agree that it might be possible, but not by any new programmer.

Comment: On the other hand, learning anything new, including and especially a programming language, is alway a good idea and I definitly do not want to discourage you. On that path I recommend to set a goal (which you have, check), select a programming language (check), start learning (check), work slowly upwards (probably check) and worry about optimisation much later (,,,). Also, take the scenic route on your way to the ultimate goal. This (cynically titled, do not get put off by it) article is very insightful in my opinion: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/

Comment: Yunnosch absolutely no offense taken! I agree one hundred percent that I am probably not the most ideal person to optimize the code. What my situation amounts to is the MATLAB code is sufficient but I know rebuilding a few functions in c++ can improve speed, and I want to use it as sort of motivation to learn the new language. As for taking the scenic route I am definitely a type that likes to learn by trial and error but I am all rather detail oriented in trying to find an elegant solution and want to learn better habits from the start